# facebook page tab application - how to check if user is banned from fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building an iframe application to be installed into a user's fan page.

I'd like to know if there's any way for my application to conclude weather the user has been banned from the page or not.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has been banned from the page, they shouldn't be able to see the app on the page.

Comment: and what if I want to respond to a user getting band (say, delete all his posts etc.)

Comment: Oh sorry, you want some kind of listener or an API you can periodically ping? I thought you were looking to gate access. Let me think about it for a while.

Comment: Ok, so there isn't currently a Graph API way to achieve this, but we'll hopefully get it out the door sometime soon.

Comment: So, this is in beta now and will push to production on Tuesday afternoon (PDT).

You can test the feature by following the details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/438/).

The correct endpoint is `https://graph.facebook.com/{pageID}/blocked?access_token=XXX` . That will return all the users blocked from that page.

You can also do `https://graph.facebook.com/{pageID}/blocked/{uid}?access_token=XXX`.

The `access_token` I'm referring to is a page access token.

Comment: I've been developing facebook applications for the last two years, and I was constantly ranting about facebook's poor treatment to its developers. You have just changed my mindset in a 180 percent angle. Is there any way I can write a positive feedback about you, perhaps to you boss or something similar (it's customary where I work)?

Comment: Don't worry about it, just glad I could help. I'd love to say I hacked together that new feature just for you, but it was going to ship this week either way, I just spotted your question ;)

Comment: Great :) is there any chance you are going to ship a way to check all admins of a facebook page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's possible. The function [admin.getBannedUsers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/admin.getBannedUsers/) returns the banned users for an application on facebook, but may also work for a page.

Comment: is there any way to get this data through the graph api? I'd rather not use the deprecated sdk

Comment: Not yet, we hope to release this soon